# Windows Built In File Server

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ftp

Consider the following situation.  You have two computers in a room.  They are connected by a LAN.  They are not connected to the internet.  They are both running clean copies of Windows 10.  They have **no usb ports or cd drives;** just the ethernet port.  Suppose I have a file on computer A, and I want to get it on computer B.  Is there any way this can be feasibly done?

In Linux, for instance, you could use netcat if that came with your system, or I think in some circumstances, you can cat the file to a special directory, or usually sftp comes preinstalled.  Is there anything like that on Windows, anything built in that can be horribly abused into performing the required function?  Ftp comes with windows, for instance, but only the client, I think.

Even manually typing out a file with the binary code for a file-sender would be...acceptable, IF it's short enough to actually memorize in a half an hour, though this method would be rather less than desirable.  You'd also need to specify how to input a binary file.  (I think you could probably use Internet Explorer and its developer tools, though I'm not sure.)

Anybody feeling creative?

Comment: Windows File Sharing. It's there in every edition of Windows and has been for the last 15+ years. In Windows 10 it is easiest if you set up a Home Group but once you've shared your files on one machine they are accessible on the other via the Network or Homegroup areas in Explorer. https://www.howtogeek.com/166407/how-to-easily-share-files-between-nearby-computers/

Comment: Oooo, right.  Yeah, that counts.

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be creative. Windows has had the ability to transfer files over the network using various means since [at least version 3.1](http://toastytech.com/guis/win311.html)

The feature is Windows File Sharing and has been enabled by default for at least the last 15 years, but has been available for more than 25 years.

In Windows 10 you can simply right click a folder and select "share with" and you will be able to quickly give access to anyone on the local Homegroup. The "old" sharing dialogue is still available by right clicking the folder and going to properties then the "Sharing" tab. The Homegroup option is a halfway house between having secured network shares and guest access and neatly removes the need for user accounts on both machines.

Micrsofts website Windows 10 [Homegroup from start to finish](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17145/windows-homegroup-from-start-to-finish) tells you how to set up a Homegroup and how to use it to share files between users.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to transfer the files would be to get a usb, but in your question you said there is none. I suggest maybe using contacts on windows, ex; computer a adds a profile on computer b, and send the files across that way. If that doesn't work, try removing the harddrive on computer a, swap computer b's drive with that, copy the file to a new location, then switch again.

Hope that was helpful:)

Comment: I notice you suggested an edit to "not connected by LAN."  They are connected by LAN; my question was mostly set up to ensure that the transfer happened through the LAN.  :P  Moving hard drives around is inventive, but I think currently the winner is the comment about Windows File Sharing - I'd forgotten that was a thing.